# Why are my Sitecore CDP and Personalize stream events failing?

Tags: personalization, cdp, sitecore-personalize

What are some common issues that can cause my stream events to fail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Target Endpoint**

An issue with the Target Endpoints results in a HTTP 401 unauthorised error when trying to send stream events.

The target endpoint is an input in the settings when loading the JavaScript. There are different target endpoints depending on the geographical region of the data centre where your tenant is hosted. To determine the geographical location of your tenant, go to the platform and check the URL. If the URL is ‘app.boxever.com’ then the environment is hosted in EU region. If the URL is ‘app-ap.boxever.com’ then the environment is hosted in the APJ region. If the URL is ‘app-us.boxever.com’ then the environment is hosted in the US region.

See the different target endpoints at: https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/developers/sitecore-customer-data-platform--data-model-2-1/javascript-tagging-examples-for-web-pages.html

**Browser Id**

An issue with the Browser Id results in a HTTP 404 not found error when trying to send stream events.

The browser id must be retrieved from the platform when sending stream events.

When using the JavaScript Library:

The following function can be used to get the browser Id when using the JavaScript Library:
Boxever.getID()
For details see: https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/developers/sitecore-customer-data-platform--data-model-2-1/javascript-tagging-examples-for-web-pages.html.

When sending server-side stream events:

The browser id must be retrieved from the platform when sending stream events. Please refer to the following documentation: https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/developers/sitecore-customer-data-platform--data-model-2-1/create-a-browser-reference-in-sitecore-cdp.html

**Browser vs Event Endpoint**

When sending server side stream events, an issue with using the browser endpoint instead of the event endpoint results in a HTTP 400 bad request error when trying to send stream events.

There are two different endpoints browser, for getting the browser id, and event ,for all other stream events. For details see: https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/developers/sitecore-customer-data-platform--data-model-2-1/create-a-browser-reference-in-sitecore-cdp.html and https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/developers/sitecore-customer-data-platform--data-model-2-1/send-an-event-as-an-http-get-request.html

**Cant find Guest in CDP**

If you are successfully sending stream event (i.e. without getting an error response) but you cannot see these events in the Sitecore CDP, this may be for the following reasons:

Finding your Guest in the Sitecore CDP

To find the correct guest in the Sitecore CDP, you can search for the guest using the Browser Id. See our documentation for more details: https://sitecore.cdpknowledgehub.com/docs/web-tagging-testing-and-troubleshooting#looking-for-your-guest

Point of Sale

For a stream event to be stored in the Sitecore CDP, the point of sale (the field called ‘pos’) on the event must be a point of sale which has been setup in your tenant. See our documentation: https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/users/sitecore-customer-data-platform/manage-points-of-sale-in-sitecore-cdp.html